# How to use REPLACE or Another Function to pass a String of customer names that have commas?

Tags: t-sql, csv, str-replace

I am trying to find a cheap fix for a legacy reporting issue that involves the following problem:

I have to pass a string of customer name to the following function

```
SET @Customerguid = REPLACE(@Customerguid,',',''',''')
```

this is a nice hack for most customers ... JUST NOT ONES WITH COMMAS IN THEIR NAME!!!!  ex:  Bills Car Shop, INC

I realize that using an ID here instead of customer name would be the right approach when they originally developed this solution but given that this data is  not properly associated with our enterprise DB I would prefer another clever hack here instead of substantial dev on a legacy product

Suggestions?

Sample Data

```
CustNameCol
Bills Car Shop, Inc
Marys Flowers
Teds Tshirt Co.
```

desired output:

```
 'Bills Car Shop, inc ','Marys Flowers','Teds Tshirt Co.'
```

Obviously the code in it's current state is not going to be able to meet this output requirement

Comment: Share sample data and desired output. One for data it works and for invalid.

Comment: Working example   Bills Car Shop, Marys Flowers

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

**[LiveDemo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/375946)**

```
CREATE TABLE #tab(CustNameCol NVARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO #tab(CustNameCol)
VALUES ('Bills Car Shop, Inc'),('Marys Flowers'),('Teds Tshirt Co.');

SELECT
    [result] = STUFF(
              (SELECT ',' + '''' + CustNameCol + ''''
               FROM #tab
               FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '');
```

Result:

```
╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║                                result                       ║
╠═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 'Bills Car Shop, Inc','Marys Flowers','Teds Tshirt Co.'     ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

*Warning:*

`CustNameCol` should be `NOT NULL`, otherwise you need to use `ISNULL(CustNameCol, '')`.